# kafka connect - Restating the worker causing rebalance issue

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Im using a 2 node Kafka Connect in distributed mode. They are running fine, but the moment when I restart the Worker service, then the connector which was running on that node went to `UNASSIGNED` then exactly after 5mins it changed to `ASSIGNED`. I don't know why this is happening, because generally, it has to move that connector's tasks to the other running node right?

Here are the logs:(after 5mins from the worker restart)

```
Rebalance started [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.WorkerCoordinator:221]
[2021-08-17 07:23:46,120] [INFO] [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=debezium-cluster1] (Re-)joining group [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:538]
[2021-08-17 07:23:46,124] [INFO] [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=debezium-cluster1] Successfully joined group with generation Generation{generationId=27, memberId='connect-1-56d39766-4974-4203-945b-6eee4fe811e7', protocol='sessioned'} [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:594]
[2021-08-17 07:23:46,128] [INFO] [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=debezium-cluster1] Successfully synced group in generation Generation{generationId=27, memberId='connect-1-56d39766-4974-4203-945b-6eee4fe811e7', protocol='sessioned'} [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:758]
[2021-08-17 07:23:46,129] [INFO] [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=debezium-cluster1] Joined group at generation 27 with protocol version 2 and got assignment: Assignment{error=0, leader='connect-1-ccdf6d6a-eeab-423c-9611-56795d0deca9', leaderUrl='http://172.30.32.13:8083/', offset=20, connectorIds=[mysql-connector-01], taskIds=[mysql-connector-01-0], revokedConnectorIds=[], revokedTaskIds=[], delay=0} with rebalance delay: 0 [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:1694]
[2021-08-17 07:23:46,129] [INFO] [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=debezium-cluster1] Starting connectors and tasks using config offset 20 [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:1244]
[2021-08-17 07:23:46,130] [INFO] [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=debezium-cluster1] Starting task mysql-connector-01-0 [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:1286]
[2021-08-17 07:23:46,131] [INFO] [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=debezium-cluster1] Starting connector mysql-connector-01 [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:1321]
```

I tried to restart the connector, but its not working.

```
curl -X POST 172.30.34.99:8083/connectors/mysql-connector-01/restart

{"error_code":409,"message":"Cannot complete request momentarily due to no known leader URL, likely because a rebalance was underway."}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause for this, Its due to Kafka's scheduled rebalance delay. An awesome blog to know more about it - https://www.confluent.io/blog/incremental-cooperative-rebalancing-in-kafka/